# How to get the Y scroll position relative to the last scroll in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the scroll Y offset since the last scroll. `window.pageYOffset` gives me the offset since the start of the page. However, I do not want this, I want the offset since the last scroll.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

Comment: I think the .pageYOffset is what you need, keep the last position and then do some math, the difference should be your scroll offset!